# Proving a set with given operations is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \mathbb{R}^2$ and define addition and scalar multiplication as follows:

$$u + v = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2\end{pmatrix}  +  \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2\end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} u_1 + v_1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}, $$

$$ku = k\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2\end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} ku_1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} $$

Show that $S$ is not a vector space by finding all vector space axioms that it does not satisfy. Show your work for all ten axioms

I found that for sure it doesn't pass the identity axiom, but I was wondering what other axioms it doesn't pass. I'm a bit hesitant to put it doesn't pass the addition is associative or communitive axiom, does it make sense it say $u_2 + v_2 = 0$ but $v_2 + u_2$ is not?

Comment: Please use MathJax throughout.

Comment: I just edited it for clarity. I'm kind of amazed that the `pmatrix` was formatted correctly but nothing else...

Comment: Next you can try to find what is the zero vector...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the main thing in this kind of problem is to make sure you use the axioms, and the definition of addition and scalar multiplication, **exactly** as they are given.

For example, to investigate the commutative law: the definition you are given says that
$$u+v=\pmatrix{u_1\cr u_2\cr}+\pmatrix{v_1\cr v_2\cr}=\pmatrix{u_1+v_1\cr0\cr}$$
and
$$v+u=\pmatrix{v_1\cr v_2\cr}+\pmatrix{u_1\cr u_2\cr}=\pmatrix{v_1+u_1\cr0\cr}\ .$$
Are these definitely always the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, that's what I'm having trouble figuring out. I don't know if v2 + u2 is the same as u2 + v2. I mean based on what you gave me I'd just say yes, but the problem says that there are multiple axioms that fail and I can only see 1 that fail

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  There isn't any $v_2+u_2$ or $u_2+v_2$ in my answer.

Comment: I'm really lost. Can you please explain again because I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Are you saying that u2 + v2 = v2 + u2? It's not in your answer explicitly, but when you add the vectors isn't that what it is?

Comment: Sorry but I really don't know what else to say.  Just look at the 2 vectors on the right hand sides in my answer - are they equal or not?

Comment: Added a bit more to answer, maybe that will help.

Comment: Do you understand that $u_1,u_2,u_2,v_2$ are **numbers** not vectors?  So the question is not asking you whether $u_2+v_2=v_2+u_2$.  And I'm sure you know whether $u_1+v_1=v_1+u_1$ or not.

Comment: Yes, I do know that u2 and v2 are numbers that are part of the vector. My question is if u2 + v2 = v2 + u2 because I want to know if addition is communitive and if it passes that axiom. I see that they are equal. I might be overthinking it because sometimes addition and multiplication is defined differently for these vectors, but if we're using the basic properties of addition I know that changing the order of numbers doesn't affect the sum

Comment: "My question is if $u_2+v_2=v_2+u_2$" - since they are numbers not vectors, I'm sure you have known the answer to this question for 12 years or more.  "If it passes that axiom" - this is not a vector space axiom, it is the statement of commutativity of addition **for numbers**.  The question is not asking you to prove this.  "Sometimes addition and multiplication is defined differently for these vectors" - yes, but that's addition and multiplication of **vectors** - addition and multiplication of **numbers** is exactly the same as you have always known it.

Comment: Hope this helps, but if not, you really need to sit down with your instructor and have a face-to-face talk.  In my experience, discussing these things online can take forever but if you can interact with someone in real time, they can work out what you are misunderstanding in 5 or 10 minutes.  Sorry if it sounds unhelpful, but I don't think I have anything else useful to say on this discussion.

Comment: So it passes the addition is communitive and associative property? The question I was given makes it sounds like there is multiple axioms that fail since it asks me to list them, but I could only find 1.

Comment: One final hint: can you find a vector $(u,v)$ such that $(1,2)+(u,v)=(1,2)$, where "$+$" means vector addition as defined in the question?

Comment: I'm just gonna assume that the vector space has associative and communitive additivity. Is that right?